# JS Highlighting a part of string

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have an example text

```
const str = 'International of Expat Health Insurance for you and your of family in Ukraine! - Fast & Secure - Free international insurance Callback - Customizable Health plans - Worldwide of Cover. International health Coverage.';
```

and i need to highlight a search request, for example `international of expat` and also i need to higlight each word what have less than three length, so in output i should have

**International of Expat** Health Insurance for you and your of family in Ukraine! - Fast & Secure - Free **international** insurance Callback - Customizable Health plans - Worldwide of Cover. **International** health Coverage.

I use next thing:

```
let query = 'international of expat';
let res = '';
let reg: RegExp;
let words = [];
const val = query.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim();

if (val.length > 0){
  words = val.split(' ');
  reg = new RegExp('(?![^<]+>)(' + words.join(' ') + ')|(' + words.filter((x) => x.length > 3).join('|') + ')', 'ig');
  res = str.replace(reg, '<strong style="font-weight: bold; color: #1D2533;">$1</strong>');
}

console.log(res);
```

but i've got incorrect result, what im missing?

Comment: Replace `')|('` in the `RegExp` declaration with `'|'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use $& instead of $1.

$& inserts the matched substring.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

```js
const str = 'International of Expat Health Insurance for you and your of family in Ukraine! - Fast & Secure - Free international insurance Callback - Customizable Health plans - Worldwide of Cover. International health Coverage.';

let query = 'international of expat';
let res = '';
let reg;
let words = [];
const val = query.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim();

if (val.length > 0){
  words = val.split(' ');
  reg = new RegExp('(?![^<]+>)(' + words.join(' ') + ')|(' + words.filter((x) => x.length > 3).join('|') + ')', 'ig');
  res = str.replace(reg, `<strong style="font-weight: bold; color: #1D2533;">$&</strong>`);
}

console.log(res);
```